# Laravel 5.1 CSRF in iframe, how to make it work?

Tags: php, laravel, iframe, csrf

I have a plugin for my app that users can implement in their website that contains a form. The problem is that I get `TokenMismatchException`when the form is submitted. From all research I've done I can see is a protection for cross-origin from Laravel.

I know I can disable it, but I don't know how I will protect the form after that?

Have any of you came across this issue? What is the best practice?

Thank you

**Note:** I've noticed that if the user has previously visited the original website and then goes to the website where the iframe is included, the Exception is not throwing anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel doesn't allow forms to be submitted from other domains, but you can set an exception.

You can add the exception in `App/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`.

```
protected $except = [
    'post/something'
];
```

Source: [EasyLaravel](http://easylaravel.com/deal-with-the-csrf-token-in-iframe)

Comment: I just answered to @Houssain Amrani that I've included it already

Comment: Are you sure the CSRF field gets rendered? Does the data gets sent to your server correctly? You can check that in FireBug or Chrome's Debug tool.

Comment: yeah man. The CSRF gets rendered, everything works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in Safari I get the TokenMismatchException

Comment: check my note in question, that's something weird, if I visit the original website the iframe works fine after. I'm thinking it might be related to cookies

Comment: I might have an idea. Add the URL the iframe gets submitted to the `$except` array in `Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96298/discussion-between-lesandru-and-alex).

Answer (score 9):

you need to change the `same_site` value in **config/session.php** .

like this

```
'same_site' => 'none',
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),
```

and set `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true` in the **.env file**.

more info check this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPz7onXjP_4)

Comment: Tried many solutions but this one worked at last :)

Answer (score 0):

if I understood the problem.
probably the submit form must have a token input that contains token session.

```
<form mothod = 'post' action = 'YourAction'>

<input type = 'hidden' name = '_token' value = '{{Session:token()}}'>
.
.
.
</form>
```

Comment: it has the token attached

Answer (score 0):

You can disable CSRF token check for the specific URL by adding the URL in **app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php** file in except array