# Laravel project within iframe - CSRF token mismatch

Tags: laravel, authentication, csrf, laravel-sanctum

I have a project where I implemented Sanctum to be used as authentication for api calls. This is the way I use it

```
axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
   axios.post('/api/login', {data: data})
   .then(response => {
     ...
   })
   .catch(error => {
     ...
   });
});
```

When I run this as a standalone page, everything works fine. But once I try to use the same url with the same data in an iframe within another project, I get a `CSRF token mismatch.` error. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946295/laravel-5-1-csrf-in-iframe-how-to-make-it-work

Comment: @SamuelFerdary yes, I saw that one but I'm concerned as to what security threats the provided solution opens? Also, it is not a submission between different domains, everything is happening on the same site/domain.

Answer (score 4):

## iframe usage and security is use case dependent.

### Security wise:

If you care about security, don't use iframes.

See:

[StackExchange: What are the security implications of having login dialog inside of an iframe](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/101076)

### Disable CSRF on specified endpoints:

If you have specific routes that don't need CSRF protection than you can make an exception for these routes in **Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php**

See:

[StackOverflow: Laravel 5 TokenMismatchException only in iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31910532/13916713)

### Go all in on iframe support:

You can edit the session settings in **config/session.php**

See:

[StackOverflow: Laravel 5.1 CSRF in iframe, how to make it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63913672/13916713)

Comment: That page within iframe is not used for traditional user login. User actually logs in in the host application and then passes a token to the iframe by which user is identified on the application within iframe. I don't really want to disable csrf check. Playing around with session config might be a step to the right direction

Answer (score 2):

Go into config/session.php, and change this:

'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true)

'same_site' => 'none',

Also, check your .env file for the value set for SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE, if it is set to false in the .env file then change it to true.